# ckeditor-duplicated-modules error with vite react project

Tags: ckeditor, vite

I have some problem with my project (React - Vite)

```
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';

import Autoformat from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat/src/autoformat';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
import Italic from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic';
import BlockQuote from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote/src/blockquote';
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import Heading from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading';
import List from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/list';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';
const editorConfiguration = {
    plugins: [Essentials, Autoformat, Bold, Italic, BlockQuote, Heading, List, Paragraph],
    toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote', 'undo', 'redo'],
};
const CkEditor = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            {/* CKEditor */}
            <CKEditor editor={ClassicEditor} config={editorConfiguration} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default CkEditor;
```

with this i have some error

```
chunk-Y6I26ZUC.js?v=e5c47c95:9145 Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules
Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules
    at chunk-25CO2O3J.js?v=e5c47c95:329:9
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: I removed the tangential question about webpack. Please ask only one question per question, and please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].